# Changing creation time for a product

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I need to change creation time of a product for my custom logic in my project for the PLP.Is it fine to alter the creation time for a product,via ImpEx?Is it recommended or can it break something else?

Answer (score 2):

Creation Time is `initial=true`, which means it can be set only once, and only during creation. It can't be edited after that. This value is automatically set by Hybris, and I wouldn't recommend changing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change it if you use `forceWrite=true` and use the `legacy` import mode (it only uses the Jalo layer).

Cf. https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8bef094d86691014a87a93789935b39b.html

However this should only be used for testing purpose. In your project you'll prefer creating a custom attribute to store your own "creation date" if you absolutely need to have logic on this info.

Also, to answer your question, modifying the creation date may impact the cache management. And if you force inconsistent values (creation in the futur or after the modification date for example) you can expect weird results.

Comment: Is it right? I tried changing creationtime in 6.7 but faild. Error message is  as below. "blablaModel.creationtime cannot be changed except during item creation"

Anyway, I succeeded it via ANSI SQL update clause in FlexibleSearch > SQL Query tab with commit mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not recommended to change it and neither you can change with any modifiers or ImpEx. Still, if you need to change, you can use SQL query to update it directly on database level.